# How does tensorflow-keras calculate the cost during training in each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When training a model with tensorflow-keras using the **fit** function, I get the cost value in each epoch.

Let's say the training set contains 100 observations and the batch size is 20, therefore, the model's weights are updated 5 times in each epoch. When the epoch is finished, it prints the cost value of that epoch. My question is the following: Is the cost value the average of 5 batches cost, or is it the cost value of the last batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can read more on this topic on [this Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10426). Insofar as I read it, it is the running average over the 5 batches.